# How to run multiple commands to save output in a file in Bash script from python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I have `shell code` and want to run two commands at a time running the `script` and saving the `output` in a `file`. how can I do that? I tried this way but got an `error` below.

> <Popen: returncode: None args: ['./hello.sh', ' > file.txt']>

```
def Test():
    st = os.stat('hello.sh')
    os.chmod('hello.sh', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
    args = ["./hello.sh", " > file.txt"]
    child_proccess = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(child_proccess)
Test()
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. If you have trouble understanding the duplicates, ask about the part you have trouble understanding. In so many words, `>` is a shell redirection operator; if you don't use `shell=True`, you can't use shell features. But the duplicate shows you how to do this elegantly without a shell.

Comment: In this case, it looks like you want `with open("file.txt", "w") as out:` `args = ["./hello.sh"]` `child_proccess = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=out)`

Comment: Also, as the documentation already tells you, and multiple duplicates emphasize, the result from `Popen` is not the output from the subprocess. There are multiple duplicates about retrieving the output from `Popen` with `communicate` but probably don't use `Popen` when what you want can easily be achieved by `check_output`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your recipe is incomplete because when you use `Popen` you also need to `communicate` and/or `wait`. Like the documentation says, you should avoid `Popen` when you can because it requires these additional elements of plumbing.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, that's true.

Comment: BTW in order that your redirection makes sense, you have to ensure that the shell processes the `>` operator. In the way you wrote it, the string `> file.txt` is simply passed as argument to `hello.sh`.